# How to see that if a Mobius transformation has a fixed point, then its conjugated to the following

Tags: complex-analysis

I've managed to show that a non-trivial Mobius transformation has 1 or 2 fixed points. Now i was asked to prove the following:

Say that $M, N$ mobius transformations are conjugated if there exists a mobius transformation $H$ such that $M \circ H = H \circ N$. Now

1) Show that if $M$ is a mobius transformation with only one fixed point, then $M$ is conjugated to a mobius transformation $N$ of the form $N(z) = az + b$

2) Show that if $M$ is a mobius transformation with exactly 2 fixed points, then $M$ is conjugated to a mobius transformation $N$ of the form $N(z) = az$

I have no idea how to prove this. Can anyone tell me, or at least give me a hint. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $M$ has $a$ as a fixed point, and $MH=HN$. Then
$$a=M(a)=MH(H^{-1}(a))=HN(H^{-1}(a))$$
and so
$$H^{-1}(a)=N(H^{-1}(a))$$
so that $H^{-1}(a)$ is a fixed point of $N$.

If $M$ has one fixed point, choose $H$ so that $H$ takes $\infty$
to the fixed point of $M$.

If $M$ has two fixed points, choose $H$ so that $H$ takes $0$ and $\infty$
to the fixed points of $M$.